# Tengo un Formulario con nombre dinámico y no logro enviar los datos por ajax

Tags: ajax, formularios, serialización

poseo una formulario que tienen un nombre tipo Formulario-(numero que va cambiando)
Pero no se como seleccionarlo cuando envio los datos.

Yo siempre envio formularios de esta forma:

```
data:$(Formulario).serialize(),
```

pero en este caso como el nombre del formulario tiene un numero asociado, no se como hacerlo...

```
data:$(Form+'-'+PostuPuesto).serialize(),
```

Pero me parece que eso no funciona porque no envia nada
Aca el codigo completo

```
$('#Form-'+PostuPuesto).on('submit',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'../phpAux/ProcesoAlta.php',
                            type:'POST',
                            data:$(Form+'-'+PostuPuesto).serialize(),
                        beforeSend: function () {
                        },            
                        success: function (resp) { 
                            if (resp.Registro < 1){
                                
                                $("#Respuesta").html("Algo Salio Mal..!");
                                $("#Respuesta").addClass("alert alert-warning");
                                $("#RespuestaEntrevista").show();
                                $("#RespuestaEntrevista").delay(8000).hide(600);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#RespuestaEntrevista").html(resp.Mensaje);
                                $("#RespuestaEntrevista").addClass("alert alert-success");
                                $("#RespuestaEntrevista").show();
                                $("#RespuestaEntrevista").delay(2500).hide(600);                                   
                                $('#ManoEntrevista-'+PostuPuesto).html('<img src="../img/perfiles-img/ConEntrevistas.png" class="imgIconoCandidatos" alt="">'); 
                            }
                        }
                    }) 
                })
```

Comment: Buenas Tardes. Ya probaste quitándole en el  data:$(Form+'-'+PostuPuesto).serialize(), la parte donde asignas el PostuPuesto ?.

Comment: Si, pero yo necesito que envie ese formulario. No entiendo, funciona sin poner el data: ?

Comment: te deje una respuesta, haber si te ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Lo que yo te recomendaría en lugar de serializar tu formulario, es que trabajes con `FormData();` Aprovechando que le estas agregando el evento submit a tu formulario podrias enviar tus datos de la siguiente manera:

```
 data: new FormData($(this)),
```

2.- Estas creando un objeto de tipo **FormData** y le pasas como parametro el formulario al cual le estas haciendo submit.

3.- Te puede interesar leer mas sobre el objeto **FormData**:

[Uso de FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData)

**NOTA: ESTA DE MAS DECIR QUE TIENES MAL TU SELECTOR:**

```
$(Form+'-'+PostuPuesto).serialize()
```

**TAL VEZ QUISISTE DECIR:**

```
$('#Form-'+PostuPuesto).serialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Deja ver si esto resuelve tu duda:

Yo tengo varios formularios en esta forma: `<form method="post" id="formCotejarBienSinEncontrar<?= $e+1?>" name="formCotejarBienSinEncontrar" >`

entonces lo que hago es que al boton que hace el submit pues tambien le pego el numero que esta relacionado con mi form:

```
<button type="submit" id="cotejarActivoEncontrado<?= $e+1?>" class="btn btn-success">Cotejar Activo</button>
```

y asi cuando llego al Ajax para enviarlo me baso en el boton, no en el formulario:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("button#cotejarActivoEncontrado<?= $e+1?>").click(function(e){ }
```

Pero en mi caso no aplico serialize por el tamaño de mi form prefiero poner cada variable que voy a mandar en el mismo formato con su numerito, y en donde se recibe en el ajax igual cada valor que voy a enviar trae su numerito  :

```
var Id_Bien = $("#id_BienSinCotejar<?= $e+1?>").val();
```

de esta manera al data le paso cada uno de los valores

```
data: { "Id_Bien": Id_Bien, "Algo_mas": Algo_mas, "Otra_cosa": Otra_cosa,
                "etc": etc
              },
```

y de esta manera envió mis datos al archivo que los recibe, es una forma de muchas que quizás puedas encontrar, así que mas bien te recomendaría revisar la sintaxis de los datos del form, tanto en el mismo form como en el Ajax por que una "," un espacio , comillas o cualquier detalle simplemente no los toma.

La otra cosa que se me ocurre es que no estas realizando el submit.

Saludos